# If else statement in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am writing the following code in vba:

```
If row_count = 28 Then Range("A28").Select
    Else
    Range("A29").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B" & row_count & ":AE" & row_count).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillDown
    End If
```

It's giving me an error that else without if.

How can i correct the code?

Answer (score 3):

Move the `Range("A28").Select` on to its own line (not as part of the `if` line), thus:

```
If row_count = 28 Then
    Range("A28").Select
Else
    Range("A29").Select
    Selection.End(xlDown).Select
    Range("B" & row_count & ":AE" & row_count).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlUp)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.FillDown
End If
```

There are [two forms](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/752y8abs.aspx) of the `if` construct, the single line and multi-line. If you put the statements for the `then` condition on the same line, it's considered a single line variant so the `else` has to also be on the same line.

Because, in your case, it's *not* on the same line, VB is assuming the single line is an `if` statement with no `else` clause, so the "naked" `else` on the next line is invalid.